# Connection property has not been initialized - Npgsql C#

Tags: c#, npgsql

I am trying to connect to my postgres database but im getting stuck with Connection property has not been initialized.

I am using a class for open connection

```
 class DBConnection
        {
            public static NpgsqlConnection conn = null;

            public void Connection_open()
            {
                string connstring = String.Format("Host=localhost;Database=Dokument_API;Username=postgres;Password=******");
                var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
                conn.Open();
            }
            public void Connection_close()
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

In form I have this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Open connection from class
            DBConnection NewConnection = new DBConnection();
            NewConnection.Connection_open();

            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO anrop (exempelanrop,beskrivning,exempelsvar) VALUES ('" + exempelanrop_text.Text + "','" + beskrivning_text.Text + "','" + exempelsvar_text.Text + "')", DBConnection.conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Uppgifter sparade");
        }
```

I get stuck on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. Why??

Comment: `DBConnection` is a bug. You *shouldn't* have a global connection. A connection should be opened right before it's used and closed as soon as possible. Locks taken while executing queries remain until a connection is closed. This means they end up blocking other connections.

Comment: Everytime you are opening the connection, where is your connection closing also you have used var conn which will neglect the static conn

Comment: If you want a generic, reusable DbConnection abstraction just use the classes already provided by ADO.NET. All ADO.NET provider classes inherit from abstract classes like DbConnection, DbCommand, DbDataReader

Comment: If you worry that opening and closing a connection is costly, don't. Most ADO.NET providers implement connection pooling. When `.Dispose()` or `.Close()` is called on a connection, it's reset and put in a connection pool, ready for reuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your method defines a local `var conn` instead of asigning to the one you define on class level. Omit `var`:

```
 conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
```

Comment: Nice catch ... did you just washed your eyes .. :)

Answer (score -1):

Remove keyword 'var' from the following statement:
var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);

Comment: Thanks! Dont know why I put it there. Ofcourse it should be gone! Thanks a lot!